# Date Header always has the same date

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, http-headers, iis-8.5

I have a server running Windows 2012 with IIS 8.5 that is hosting several sites. For every response that is returned from a client request to any of the sites the Date header has the same value:

```
Key     Value
Date    Wed, 09 Mar 2016 17:07:56 GMT
```

I have checked the HTTP Header options in IIS, and do not have any thing for the Date Header set. There is no code that is setting it programmatically. The server itself has the correct time.

I believe the incorrect date is causing intermittent issues with Chrome storing session cookies for the sites.

I have three other servers running the exact same sites and code, all of which are load balanced. These three all have the correct date in the date header.

Is there a way to correct this anywhere in a config or setting? I am not understanding why this would have started happening randomly on one of the servers.

I thought I would check here before I go resetting IIS or giving it a reboot.

Thanks

UPDATE: I did follow the steps in the answer to this -> [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/217343/date-header-returned-by-iis7-is-wrong). It fixed the date issue. However, I still have no idea how the date header got set and stuck at a future date in the first place.

P.S. I did a google search on the date and it turns out there will be a [total solar eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_March_9,_2016) on that day.